# Image align error in FPDF

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, fpdf

I am working with laravel to make a report using FPDF. It runs properly but every bottom page's image is not aligned correctly. I mentioned that with image. How can I fix it? I am working with that long time. Here is my code. 
Thanks in advance.

```
public function img_pdf_full()
  {


    $data= visitor::where('flag', '1')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();       

    $pdf = new PDF_Code128(); //'P','mm',array(58,20)
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Visitor's Log",0,0,'C');
    $pdf->Ln();

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
    $pdf->Cell(12,10,'Photo',1,0,'C',0);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Name',1,0,'C',0);
    $pdf->Cell(20,10,'Visitor ID',1,0,'C',0);
    $pdf->Cell(20,10,'Date',1,0,'C',0);
    $pdf->ln();

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
    foreach ($data as $v) {
        $image1 = public_path('storage/'.$v->v_photo);
        $new_date = date("d F, Y", strtotime($v->v_date));

        $pdf->Cell(12,10, $pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 11.5,10) ,1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$v->v_name,1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$v->v_id,1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$new_date,1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->ln();
    }

    $pdf->ln();


    $pdf->Output();
    exit;

}
```

[image]

Comment: what happen when you put `$pdf->Cell(12,10, $pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 1,1) ,1,0,'C',0);`

Comment: It runs properly but every bottom page's image is not aligned correctly. I have uploaded an image . Here image should be in the box. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the position of y is at bottom then add page and set y to initial of next page. You can do code like:-

```
            y = $pdf->GetY()
            if (y > 275){
                $pdf-> AddPage()
                $pdf->SetY(20)
                y = $pdf->GetY()
             }
```

You can set position of Y according to your requirement. Your code will be something like:-

```
foreach ($data as $v) {
        $image1 = public_path('storage/'.$v->v_photo);
        $new_date = date("d F, Y", strtotime($v->v_date));
        // code added by me
        y = $pdf->GetY()
        if (y > 275){
            $pdf-> AddPage()
            $pdf->SetY(20)
            y = $pdf->GetY()
         }

        $pdf->Cell(12,10, $pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(),y, 11.5,10) ,1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$v->v_name,1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$v->v_id,1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->Cell(20,10,$new_date,1,0,'C',0);
        $pdf->ln();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, adapting the answer of Rupal. In my case i used multicell, with an array inside the foreach, to generate the rows + image.
my code before:

```
$pdf->SetWidths(Array(25,50,60,40,20));
$pdf->SetAligns(Array('L','L','L','L','C'));
$pdf->SetLineHeight(6);
$json = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
define('EURO',chr(128));
    
    foreach($json as $item){
     //write data using Row() method containing array of values.
     $pdf->Row(Array(
         $pdf->Image($item['img_url'],$pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(),25), 
         utf8_decode($item['articulo']), utf8_decode($item['art_descripcion']), 
         utf8_decode($item['envase']), utf8_decode($item['precio']).EURO,
                    ));
       }
```

My code after with the arrangement;

```
$pdf->SetWidths(Array(25,50,60,40,20));
$pdf->SetAligns(Array('L','L','L','L','C'));
$pdf->SetLineHeight(6);
$json = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
define('EURO',chr(128));
    
    foreach($json as $item){
     //write data using Row() method containing array of values.
     $pdf->Row(Array(
         $pdf->Image($item['img_url'],$pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(),25), 
         utf8_decode($item['articulo']), utf8_decode($item['art_descripcion']), 
         utf8_decode($item['envase']), utf8_decode($item['precio']).EURO,
                    ));
     // arrangement for jumping last image row in multicell
               $y = $pdf->GetY();
               if ($y > 250){
                     $pdf-> AddPage();
                     $pdf->SetY(20);
                    $y = $pdf->GetY();
         }
              // End arrangement
       }
```

You can modify this line

```
if ($y > 250){
```

to get the exact point where your image doesn't print on the correct row

[Image BEFORE / AFTER arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TkHZ.png)